# Python Tokenizer: Word Limit

Tags: python

I written a tokenizer for my language in python, but when I try to tokenize a file, it only tokenizes it to a limit. It tokenizer only to around 90 tokens (words and symbols separately), when it's supposed to tokenize all the file.
Here's the code:

```
import re

file = input("filename>")

with open(file, 'r') as myfile:
data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')


scanner = re.Scanner([
 (r"[0-9]+",                   lambda scanner,token:("NUMBER", token)),
 (r"[a-z_A-Z_λ]+",             lambda scanner,token:("KEYWORD", token)),
 (r"[,.!#%^*()']+",            lambda scanner,token:("OPERATOR", token)),
 (r'["]+',                     lambda scanner,token:("OPERATOR", token)),
 (r"[+-]+",                    lambda scanner,token:("OPERATOR", token)),
 (r'[=]+',                     lambda scanner,token:("OPERATOR", token)),
 (r"[{}]+",                    lambda scanner,token:("OPERATOR", token)),
 (r'[[]]+',                    lambda scanner,token:("OPERATOR", token)),
 (r"\s+", None), # None == skip token.
])

results, remainder = scanner.scan(data)

print(results)
```

The example script is (for those who have time to read):

```
constant Flow = "Flow"
constant script = this

local names = {'Gabriel', 'Kauan', 'Laura', 'Tarsila'}
constant flowCountry = 'Brasil'

local void function getinpairs(name) extends findArg()
    for _, v(name) in pairs(names) do
       private local table = names
       print("Flow being the best programming language for you, has implemented     some new arguments!")
       local flowFounder = names[1]
       local namesMetatable = getmetatable(t1)
  end
end

function findArg(name)
    return getinpairs(name)
end

findArg('Gabriel')
```

And the result is (for those who have time to read):

```
[('KEYWORD', 'constant'), ('KEYWORD', 'Flow'), ('OPERATOR', '='), ('OPERATOR', '"'), ('KEYWORD', 'Flow'), ('OPERATOR', '"'), ('KEYWORD', 'constant'), ('KEYWORD', 'script'), ('OPERATOR', '='), ('KEYWORD', 'thislocal'), ('KEYWORD', 'names'), ('OPERATOR', '='), ('OPERATOR', '{'), ('OPERATOR', "'"), ('KEYWORD', 'Gabriel'), ('OPERATOR', "',"), ('OPERATOR', "'"), ('KEYWORD', 'Kauan'), ('OPERATOR', "',"), ('OPERATOR', "'"), ('KEYWORD', 'Laura'), ('OPERATOR', "',"), ('OPERATOR', "'"), ('KEYWORD', 'Tarsila'), ('OPERATOR', "'"), ('OPERATOR', '}'), ('KEYWORD', 'constant'), ('KEYWORD', 'flowCountry'), ('OPERATOR', '='), ('OPERATOR', "'"), ('KEYWORD', 'Brasil'), ('OPERATOR', "'"), ('KEYWORD', 'local'), ('KEYWORD', 'void'), ('KEYWORD', 'function'), ('KEYWORD', 'getinpairs'), ('OPERATOR', '('), ('KEYWORD', 'name'), ('OPERATOR', ')'), ('KEYWORD', 'extends'), ('KEYWORD', 'findArg'), ('OPERATOR', '()'), ('KEYWORD', 'for'), ('KEYWORD', '_'), ('OPERATOR', ','), ('KEYWORD', 'v'), ('OPERATOR', '('), ('KEYWORD', 'name'), ('OPERATOR', ')'), ('KEYWORD', 'in'), ('KEYWORD', 'pairs'), ('OPERATOR', '('), ('KEYWORD', 'names'), ('OPERATOR', ')'), ('KEYWORD', 'do'), ('KEYWORD', 'private'), ('KEYWORD', 'local'), ('KEYWORD', 'table'), ('OPERATOR', '='), ('KEYWORD', 'names'), ('KEYWORD', 'print'), ('OPERATOR', '('), ('OPERATOR', '"'), ('KEYWORD', 'Flow'), ('KEYWORD', 'being'), ('KEYWORD', 'the'), ('KEYWORD', 'best'), ('KEYWORD', 'programming'), ('KEYWORD', 'language'), ('KEYWORD', 'for'), ('KEYWORD', 'you'), ('OPERATOR', ','), ('KEYWORD', 'has'), ('KEYWORD', 'implemented'), ('KEYWORD', 'some'), ('KEYWORD', 'new'), ('KEYWORD', 'arguments'), ('OPERATOR', '!'), ('OPERATOR', '"'), ('OPERATOR', ')'), ('KEYWORD', 'local'), ('KEYWORD', 'flowFounder'), ('OPERATOR', '='), ('KEYWORD', 'names')]
```

It stops at line 11: word "name".

Someone could point the error on the script?

Comment: BTW: did you see [PLY - Python Lex-Yacc](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/index.html) which you can use to create own language ?

Comment: Well, I know that exists but as an ambicious guy with 0 experience in python, I don't know how to use it, so I made this simple lexer for my programming language using my luck of finding tutorials. By the way,  this programming language will be called Flow and is inspired by Lua.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the brackets:

```
r'[[]]+'
```

should be

```
r'[\[\]]+'
```